# React.js - Array.unshift() not updating array on front-end

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-dnd

I have a small implementation of drag and drop using [`react-dnd`](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd). There are two columns, dragging from right side column to the left one activates the specific status item.

On drop, `pushCard()` is called, which (as the name suggests), pushes the dragged item into the array of activated statuses i.e., `status_data`.

But the problem is, `status_data.push(itemToPush)`, pushes the new item at the end of the array. I wanted to push the item on top of the array i.e., index 0 of the array.

`status_data.unshift(itemToPush)` works in this case, but `unshift` only updates the array in the `state` and on the backend, but it doesn't show the updated `array` on the front-end. Rather it would just keep pushing the same element that was dragged first.

[Simple description of problem in a GIF.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3hMH.gif)

**`pushCard`:**

```
pushCard(item) {
    const { status_data } = this.state.template;
    const itemToPush = {
        title : item.title || 'CUSTOM',
        type_id : item.type_id,
        color : item.color || '#000',
        type: item.type,
        require_notes: item.require_notes || false,
        require_estimate: item.require_estimate || false
    };
    status_data.unshift(itemToPush);
    this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.template, { status_data }));
}
```

**`renderActiveStatuses`**

```
renderActiveStatuses() {
    let renderedResult = '';
    if (this.state.template.status_data.length < 0) {
      renderedResult = (<p>No status active in this template.</p>);
    } else {
      renderedResult = this.state.template.status_data.map((status, i) => {
        return (
          <Status deleteStatus={this.deleteStatus} handleStatusUpdate={this.onStatusUpdate} index={i} id={status.id} moveCard={this.moveCard} statusData={status} key={status.id} />
        );
      });
    }
    return renderedResult;
}
```

`renderActiveStatuses` is called in the `render` function of the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `status` objects, like the `itemToPush` that you show here, have no property `id`, the one you are using as a `key` in `Status`. You can try `key={i}` instead (even if using the map index is not the best idea).

You can generate a (probably) unique ID like this:

```
const itemToPush = {
    id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16), 
    ...
}
```

and use `status.id` now as you did before.

There are better ID generators if there is any risk in the case you generate millions of these.

Comment: If I do `key={i}`, that confuses `react-dnd`. As it needs a unique `index` for each item.

Comment: The `id` of `Status` will be wrong, too. You can try something like `status.title + status.type_id + i`. Otherwise, you will need a factory for your status items that generates a random ID for them, i.e. a function that returns one of these items given its type, adding an ID to the object.

Comment: Updated with an ID generator.

Comment: Sounds awesome. I was going to use `Math.random()` but this one sound much better solution. Thank you very much @JulienD

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation so I can't upvote the question :P Otherwise I would've loved to :) Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
this.setState({template: Object.assign({}, this.state.template, { status_data })});
```

As you did in your question, you are only assigning to your state the contents of `this.state.template`, while the original one never changes, so your state becomes

```
state = {
    template: {status_data: ...},
    status_data: ...,
    ...
}
```

Comment: You probably want `Object.assign({}, this.state.template, { status_data })` so that you are [not modifying state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Comment: @JulienD thanks. But this doesn't solve the problem :9

Comment: So now the state is changing correctly, but the view does not, so you need to show us the view here, we hardly guess without.

Comment: I think, in the `renderActiveStatuses` function, `key={status.id}` has something to do with not updating the view. As new statuses doesn't have a key, at least note before going to the server. @JulienD could that be an issue?

Comment: Yes, that is the alternative answer I just wrote.

Comment: This should use [the callback version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).